# Calling enter key inside the SAP

Tags: excel, vba

I create a macro to extract a file from SAP and i try to record step by step before copying the script from visual basic in Excel the code is working fine but in the last row of code the script is stop to click the save button. but my record is full until to save the button. seeking for help to SAP and VBA Click the Save button or call enter function in SAP to VBA Below is my code.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").DoubleClickNode "F00007"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCR:ZFIR093:0100/ctxtS_SYDAT").Text = "12/31/2018"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCR:ZFIR093:0100/ctxtS_BUKRS").Text = caompnay code
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCR:ZFIR093:0100/ctxtS_HKONT-LOW").Text = code
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCR:ZFIR093:0100/ctxtS_POSTD").Text = "12/31/2018"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCR:ZFIR093:0100/ctxtS_POSTD").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCR:ZFIR093:0100/ctxtS_POSTD").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").Press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").Press
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[3]/menu[1]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
```

Comment: Please add the code to the question itself instead of linking to a picture, that would make easier to answer. Of course you should redact out sensitive information, and even better if you could reproduce the same problem without relying on it.

Comment: Aplogies Lyth here 's the code.

Comment: Post has been edited thanks :)

Comment: Which transaction do you use? What do you mean by "extract a file"? Do you download an excel file and do you get a file dialog "Save as"?

Comment: i want to full a data from SAP .. extraction of data

Comment: Yes the Script is stop to the file dialog to click the Save button.

Comment: Sorry, this is not helpful. Could you please have look at my questions otherwise [this](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1487670) might help

Comment: session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[3]/menu[1]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press

Comment: session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8  -- this is the enter button? @Storax

Comment: What SapGui version do you have? If it's 7.40 or less you probabyl need to use Win API functions. You can't control it via SapGui Scripting

Comment: its 7.20 sir @Storax

Comment: Then you are probably out of luck. Have a look [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/26/new-scripting-option-in-sap-gui-for-windows-730-pl-8/). You need to use API functions to control the windows dialog like I said in my earlier comment. But as you do not tell which transaction you use it's kind of guessing.

Comment: even the file dialog is inside the SAP not in windows?

Comment: I think it is a windows dialog called from sapgui. And you can't control it via Sapgui scripting, see also SAP note 1974590 (you need a SAP oss user to access it). Again, as you do not tell which transaction you use it's difficult to help. Sorry but should be a little bit more talkative

Comment: im sorry im new from SAP so i do not know the transaction , only to record the SAP and transfer the vbscript to excel.

Comment: I am afraid but if you are not even able to find out the transaction you are using then it does not really make sense trying to help you. This is spoon feeding then. Sorry!!

Comment: @Storax thanks for your advise appreciated :)

Comment: what i only need to know is the enter key inside the SAP.

Comment: This will not really help you but anyway you send Enter with _session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0_